# Can perl replace multiple substrings with regex?

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I have some substring `[ aa bb cc ]` in a line, like `$line = "1 2 a b [ aa bb cc ] c d [ bb cc ] 3 4"`. And I want to trim all the spaces in these substrings. The following code does not work.

```
while($line =~ /\[(.*?)\]g/)
{
  $1 =~ s/\s+//g;
}
```

Can someone help please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s{\[(.*?)\]}{
   my $s = $1;
   $s =~ s/\s+//g;
   $s
}eg;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I got some error with this code:Backslash found where operator expected at ../convtag.pl line 11, near "$s =~ s/\"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 9)
 (Missing operator before \?)
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at ../convtag.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$s" requires explicit package name at ../convtag.pl line 9.
syntax error at ../convtag.pl line 11, near "$s =~ s/\"
Substitution pattern not terminated at ../convtag.pl line 11.

Comment: @ikegami interesting substitution notation

Answer (score 2):

Another way similar to your attempt:

```
while($line =~ s/\[([^\]\s]*)\s+/[$1/g) {}
```

and you don't have to escape the r-square bracket, but it helps vim.

Answer (score 0):

Your method fails because the match variable `$1` is read-only.  You can use non-destructive substitution (introduced in Perl 5.16) to avoid that problem:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $line = "[foo bar] [   baz    ]  sproing";
while($line =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g)
{
    my $result = $1 =~ s/\s+//gr;
    print "|$result|\n";
}
```